# Git like system to manage a system configuration

Tags: linux, administration

Is there a way to manage the configuration of a linux system in a similar way git manages the structure of a folder?
In other words, Is it possible to save snapshots of a current working status and then try out some alternative configuration in a "separate branch" ?

Context:
I started using linux as my main machine again since several years of inactivity. I used Slackware and had lots of fun running it into my former machines. 
Currently i'm using Arch on a laptop and sometimes i find myself editing files, installing packages and experimenting with some configurations.
Editing /etc/ files and installing packages can often have dangerous outcomes and It would be nice to have the possibility to roll-back to a working state.

Comment: You could try to create a Git (or other VCS) repo on your `/etc/` diretcory. Setting up the `.gitignore` will be a complete nightmare, but absolutely necessary to avoid an OS implosion. Apart from that, there are not a lot of things that can be managed this way. IMHO the best way to manage your installed packages is a packages manager, a pencil, and a sheet of paper. And if you know your package manager well enough, the last two are even optional.

Comment: Depending on the scale you could also consider Chef/Puppet etc. tools to do this. Though they work differently. Also your filesystem might support actual snapshots. Usually there is no branching. After all your current configuration is just going to be the active one.

Comment: What you are looking for is ´configuration management` like puppet, ansible, salt, chef ....

Answer (score 1):

The [etckeeper](http://etckeeper.branchable.com/) project is designed to maintain your `/etc` configuration under version control, with `git` being one of the supported VCSs.